# Change default language in jhipster

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, jhipster, angular-translate

I use JHipster 2.27.0

I set the language in the `weapp/scripts/app.js` file by changing the preferred language line, for instance `$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');`changes the language to french.

This solution work it in run and I have any javascript tests (`dev`) OK but I have any javascript tests (`prod`) KO.

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Controller Tests ActivationController calls Auth.activateAccount with the key from stateParams FAILED
    Error: Plural Function not found for locale: fr
        at MessageFormat (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/messageformat/messageformat.js:9)
        at G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat/angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat.js:9
        at interpolationFactoryAdder (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js:9)
        at forEach (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js:9
        at invoke (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9
        at getService (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at invoke (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9
        at forEach (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at createInjector (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9)
        at workFn (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:9)
        at G:/workspace/myapp270/src/main/webapp/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:9
        at mockApiAccountCall (G:/workspace/myapp270/src/test/javascript/spec/helpers/httpBackend.js:9)
```

**Do you know where to set the default language in tests?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `main/webapp/bower_components/messageformat/locale/fr.js` to the list of files to load in browser in `src/test/javascript/karma.conf.js` file.

Comment: When I add this line before `// endbower`, this line disappear on run. But if I add this line after `// endbower` is OK. WORK IT now. Thank.

Comment: Yes the lines between `// bower:js` and `// endbower` are injected by gulp or grunt according to the dependencies in `bower.json`, same as for `index.html`.

Comment: By the way, next release will let you choose default language when generating your app, so this will be much easier. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/2970

Comment: Chose wrong default language while generating. How to change it now? There is no such folder called 'bower_components' in the generated code.

Comment: Yalendra Goel please open your own question